# solving java program cascading puzzle

Tags: java

I am solving a puzzle. their would be 2 parameter. Suppose i give a= 7 then 7 would be maximum value and if b give 1 then it will delete 2b and 2b+1 from a. i.e 1, 2 and 3 will be deleted and these 2,3 will again be parameter.

```
ok if
input 1 =7
input 2 =1 
input 3 ={1}
 input3 i.e {1} will clear 2i and 2i+1 so {2,3} and {2,3} will clear{4,5,6,7}


output={0}

and if 
input 1 =7
input 2 =2
input 3 ={2,7}

output={1,3,6}
```

{2,7} so 2 will clear 2 as well as 4 and 5. but 7 will clear only 7. so we will get 1,3,6. i hope it lil bit clear now

```
 Arraylist li = new arraylist{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

    if(2b>n and 2b+1>n)

    li.remove{2b}
    li.remove{2b+1}.
```

but how to reuse it second time.

Comment: you have to be a bit clearer, what youre actually asking is very difficult to follow, it appears as though recursion will be a viable option, but without being crystal clear on the question an answer is impossible.

Comment: Could you refactor your question, it's hard to understand what you're asking, the English isn't quite clear; also, could you format the code with the correct, 4-space indent - please.

Comment: And please make the code actually compilable, Java code. `li.remove{2b}` is not Java.

Comment: This edit has made the question no more clear than the original, maybe a full-sentence English explanation would be more clear rather than trying to condense the question.

Comment: It would help if you are concequent with your variable names. I am guessing that `a == input1 == n == N`?

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of loop that ends when a condition is met. This condition is unclear from your answer, but I guess that it should continue while `2b + 1 < a`.

You'd get something like this (note that this is *pseudocode*, I'll leave the real code for you as the puzzle):

```
li = arraylist(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
a = 7
b = 1

while(2b+1 < n) {
  // Remove items
  li.remove(2*b)
  b = li.removeAndGetValue(2*b+1)

  // Reduce a by 2
  a = a - 2
}
```

In this code `b` is updated with the value of `li[2*b+1]` (as I understood from your question, but it was a bit vague)